# Loading order for multiple libraries (isotope + boostrap + jquery + json data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, libraries, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to make tooltips appear when hovering over an image in isotope cards, for that I wanted to use the boostrap library. But it only works with hardcoded elements in the html not for elements loaded from an js script. What am I missing?

The order in which I load the libraries are:

```html
<head>
  <!-- tooltips background -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom_style.css">

  <!-- isotope library and jquery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- boostrap for tooltips -->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <script src="custom_scripts.js">/script>
</head>
<body> 
  ...
  some hardcoded code that works and shows the tooltip with the boostrap and isotope logic
  ...
</body>
```

And in `custom_scripts.js`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


   function isotopeCode(){
      ...
      isotope logic
   }

   // ========= load data from two json files =========
   let json = {};
   var ability_translation = {};

   $.getJSON("ability_translation.json", function(traducciones) {
      ability_translation = traducciones;
   });

   $.getJSON("data.json", function(datos){
      ...
      some logic
      ...
   }).then(() => isotopeCode());

});
```

I apologize in advance if the problem is duplicated but I could not find it on stackoverflow.

I tried to change the order in which the elements are loaded in different ways (in the html) but all without success (even put some parts at the end of the body)

What I am trying to achieve is that after the json elements are loaded (having loaded the cards tooltips in the DOM) the boostrap library is applied, so it can show the tooltip with the characteristic boostrap black background along with the posibilities of this library.
So i want that Boostrap is the last thing to load (If I am not mistaken the boostrap logic only works after the json elements have been loaded into the DOM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, event listeners that are added to elements on the page when the document is ready can't be added to elements that are not yet on the page. This is a common problem. You'll need to add handlers to elements loaded after the original page load manually. Or consider a different approach entirely.

Update:

I think your issue is mostly one of timing. It appears that `$.getJSON` is async, and you're calling it twice. What you need to do is initialize your tooltip code after both of these return. There are patterns already created for us to execute after async code, and that is usually using promises.

If you want to execute something after multiple async calls you should consider reaching for `Promise.all()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

The api for promises has been standardized at this point, but I'm not sure that jQuery implements the standard. Mosty developers have moved on from jQuery these days, as many of the solutions it offered are better solved by a transpiling step common to modern JS development.

But to offer a potential solution using the code you have (instead of or before trying promises) why not try the following, which basically manually wires up the things you want to do in the order you want to do them. Bear in mind that this type of manual wiring up doesn't scale well, and also defeats some of the power of async requests by serializing them:

```js
function isotopeCode(){
  ...
  isotope logic
}

function initTooltips(){
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
}

$.getJSON("ability_translation.json", function(traducciones) {
  ability_translation = traducciones;
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(datos){
    ...
    some logic
    ...
    initTooltips() 
  })
});
```

If `$.getJSON` implements proper promises, the following is a better approach, or you might have to convert them to the `fetch()` api, and not use jQuery.

```js
const promise1 = $.getJSON("ability_translation.json", function(traducciones) {
  ability_translation = traducciones;
});

const promise2 = $.getJSON("data.json", function(datos){
  ...
  some logic
  ...
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then((values) => {
  isotopeCode();
  initTooltips();
});
```

Comment: sorry for the dumb question, what could be another approach? or what is the recommended way to handle this kind of common problems? any search terms is more than welcome!

Comment: Could you post the code that you're using to initialize the bootstrap tooltips? It's probably not an issue with the order your library files are loading but when the initialization code runs. If you're just loading the json data once, it might be a tolerable approach to delay your tooltip initialization until after the json loads (I assume this is async). If you have elements appearing all the time on your page, the bootstrap approach of manual initialization is a bit tedious. Any front-end framework like React, Vue, Angular etc would have more powerful ways of assigning this type of behavior.

Comment: thanks, although it does not contain the keyword I do not know if it is async. Here is the initialization of the boostrap tooltips in the same js file
`$(function () {
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
 })`

Comment: The `$()` is the jquery ready function https://api.jquery.com/ready, which executes as soon as the dom is ready. So this is executing before the json is loaded. Instead you need to execute the code inside of `$()` AFTER the elements from JSON are added to the dom. I'll update my answer to show what I think might work.

Comment: wow, thats a really detail answer, unfortunately neither of the two solutions could solve my problem, however, it is very helpful for me to know the structure of the promises for this case and the alternatives.
I will take your advice and try another approach, while I continue to learn. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Update: It was a stupid typo combined with my problem, that's why it didn't worked in the previous comment. Now both of the solutions work perfect. You are awesome!!!